# How to pipe command's output to program and keep its stdin open

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

for example, I want to to send `print(32) to python and it should print 32 and remain open until I press ctrl+d

I did following

```bash
echo 'print(32)' | python
```

but It just prints 32 and closes the python.

I want to keep the Python's interactive shell open to send further commands from my keyboard.

EDIT:
that was just example. instead of python it could be `node`, `ruby` or `docker exec -it` command.

basically I want to pipe output as if I was typing via my keyboard

Comment: I think this is not _keeping_ it open, but first have stdin connected to your pipe, and when the pipe closes, reopen stdin to your tty.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-i` flag to ask python to inspect interactively after running a script, combine with process substitution `<(..)` construct in bash. This will let the python command assume the commands are coming from a file even though it *isn't*

```sh
python -i <(echo 'print(32)')
32
>>>
```

or set the [PYTHONINSPECT](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONINSPECT) variable to a non-empty string to emulate the `-i` behavior

```sh
PYTHONINSPECT=x python <(echo 'print(32)')
```

Note that Process substitution is not supported in POSIX mode, but on bash/zsh or ksh93 only.

Comment: Sorry for XY problem. I used python just as an example for my problem. please see edit

Comment: I don't think there is a one size fits all solution for this. Each tool might have its own implementation of interactive session handling

Answer (score 1):

If you are in xwindow with xdotool install, the behaviour can be simulated with :

```
#!/bin/bash
        
feed_initial_input(){
    local initial_input="$1"; shift
    { sleep 0.3; xdotool type "$initial_input"$'\n'; } &
    "$@"
}

feed_initial_input "print(32)" python
feed_initial_input "console.log('Hello world!')" node
```